# BigCommerce out of stock for greater than 0 stock

Tags: bigcommerce

How to change the DEFAULT 'Out of Stock' number from Zero to "5" in Bigcommerce? To be safe and show the "Out of Stock" notices once a product item stock level reaches "5" rather than the default of "0".

Tried everything on Bigcommerce, but this needs to be a programming fix.

Comment: If you show out of stock, the shopper won't ve able to buy. Why doesn't the customer enter 5 less items in the stock count?

Comment: Thought of this too, but too many products to do this manually. Need a "trigger" fix for the Sold Out notice on each product.